# How to achieve the real cd in python?

Tags: python, cd

I'm writing a tool to make my jump convenient.
After executing following command,

```
./main.py  /etc
```

the current path is actually jump to `/etc`.

If I use `os.chdir` in `main.py`, then the current path would pop to the original path which is  no what I expected.

How can I change the real current path in python ?

Comment: You *are* changing "the real current path"... of your Python process. Not your shell's current directory. Only your shell can change its own directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell and your Python script are running as two different processes. Each process have a distinct working directory. Changing the working directory in one process does not effect the working directory of any other process.

That's why the shell `cd` command can't be created as an external program.

Comment: So there is no way to custom a `cd` command?

Comment: @haoli No there isn't. If you need a "custom" `cd` command, then you could create it as a function in the shell to perform whatever other actions you might need, then invoke the shells built-in `cd` command.

Comment: Well, [*you could*](https://github.com/robertswiecki/extcd) bully the target program into `cd`ing to a different folder using `ptrace(2)`... but I would not suggest it for any reason other than having fun and exploring new interesting ways of breaking your system.